# Read binary file from a position in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-io, filestream, file-read

I want to read a binary file from a particular position. I am using the following code but that is not working.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
fs.Seek(len,SeekOrigin.Current);
int bytesRead = fs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

It starts reading from beginning.

Comment: What does the `Seek` return? What is the value of `len`?

Comment: len is the point from where i want seek to begin. It is int64

Comment: We know what `len` is: that's why I asked for its value, and the return value.

Comment: File length = 1513411 and len = 134213 return value of seek is same as len

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fs.Seek(len,SeekOrigin.Begin);
```